# Is there a way to know all possible places in code where the system may interchange threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm reading a book called "Java Concurrency In Practice" and in the first chapter the following code is demonstrated as thread unsafe

```
public class UnsafeSequence {
   private int value;

   /** Returns a unique value. */
   public int getNext() {
      return value++;
   }
}
```

So if two threads run this code we can get unwanted results because they will interchange in different steps such as reading, modifying and writing the value. Is this determined only by OS, or do threads switch between each other on different "bytecode commands" for example? Is there any way to know all possible places where threads might switch from one to another, not just for this code but in general?

Comment: "not just for this code but in general?" No. Even for this code, no.

Comment: Its all about thread scheduling!!

Comment: if that was easy to do, concurrency wouldn't be so hard :)

Comment: Somewhat same idea as the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), tough you do not want to determine if the program finishes, but if any code is not thread safe. Problem is, the computer does not know when something is safe or not - that is the task of the developer.

Comment: Sure, but I don't understand how there is not like a small unit of code that processor must execute and that there is no way that this small portion of code, like just one assembly instruction, is executed by two threads interchangeably

Comment: If you mean "at what parts of some code could there be a thread switch" then it it _might_ be possible if you'd know all the bytecode instructions but it's normally not worth bothering. Instead you can think of "if my code is not threadsafe and used by different threads, all sorts of weird things can happen - even kittens may die ;) "

Comment: "this small portion of code, like just one assembly instruction" - that's your error: this small piece of code is more than just one assembly instruction.

Comment: @DaniloGacevic there is no minimum code unit, we even built multiple CPUs into one chip precisely to allow threads to run in parallel. Defining thread switching points would defeat the entire purpose of multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

As several comments note, no. Two things you can do:

Write your classes in a thread-safe manner, so that thread scheduling isn't an issue.

Use concurrency support to prevent issues.

Keep reading the book.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to know all possible places where threads might switch from one to another, not just for this code but in general?

This question is a bit vagiue. Let me split it up in two parts:

1. Two threads can wander over the same piece of code and happily interleave, except:

   - inside atomic operations (including complex operations inside of thread-safe classes)
   - inside guarded blocks (e.g. using a synchronized block, lock, semaphore, or some other memory fence)
2. Threads can switch all the time, which is 100% up to the OS. In theory a thread might even never get a chance to be 'scheduled in' again if the OS decides so. Threads may die spuriously (e.g. killed in ProcessExplorer). You never know when a thread will be stopped in it's tracks (suspended), but you do know that if it happens inside an atomic operation, no other thread will enter that code until the suspended thread resumes and completes the operation.

Answer (score 0):

It happens whenever the system scheduler feels like. It has nothing to do with the JVM if the JVM only passes that scheduling to the native processor.